# Gallery Shortcode: using link attribute to link to a specific image size

Tags: customization, gallery

When `[gallery link="file"]` is used, it calls the original image file source.

It it possible to create a shortcode filter that links to a specific size, like:

`[gallery link="medium"]`

or

`[gallery link="custom-size-name"]`

(referring to an additional image size created with `add_image_size()` in functions.php.)

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18178 is different patch for [gallery] shortcode enhancement. From the looks of it, I think patching this feature into the core shouldn't be much of an issue complexity wise.

Comment: +1. even 3 years later, and after the recent gallery revamps, this is still an issue - especially if you use a lightbox in conjunction with the wordpress gallery. there needs to be a size option here to stop users having to download 4 meg images to view in a 800x600 lightbox...

Answer (score 3):

I found something very close that works here:

http://oikos.org.uk/2011/09/tech-notes-using-resized-images-in-wordpress-galleries-and-lightboxes/

Answer (score 0):

Short of de-registering the built in shortcode tag, copying the function and re-registering it with some modifications you could filter on `wp_get_attachment_link`. The problem is this affects everywhere that function is used.

Saying that it might not be such a bad thing:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'my_attachment_link', 10, 6 );
function my_attachment_link( $link, $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text ) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        // if we're linking to the file itself
        if ( ! $permalink )
            $link = preg_replace("/href=\'([^\']+)\'/", "href='" . wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'my-custom-size', false ) . "'", $link );
    }
    return $link;
}
```

This will override any links generated to the original size file on the front end with a link to the size you specify in the second argument in `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

Comment: Just realised this is basically what the oikos.org.uk example is